# Как настроить раскладку вручную для конкретного языка - Windows 10 и Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-10

Можно ли изменить раскладку для клавиатуры вручную в Windows 11 (или в Windows 10 хотя бы скажите как)?
 
Дело в том, что клавиатура у меня русско-английская (как у большинства из нас). Я добавил сербский язык. Теперь могу запросто набрать буквы `č ć š`. НО, теперь при наборе английская буква `Y (англ. раскладка) = Z (серб. раскладка)`, а `Z (англ. раскладка) = Y (серб. раскладка)`. 
Также я не могу найти клавишу, которая выводила бы букву `Ž`.
Вопрос в том, что хотел бы настроить отдельные виды клавиш по своему, вручную привязав их к клавишам на своё усмотрение (как в играх смена назначения клавиш).
С уважением,
Степан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно тебе поможет Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.

Ссылка на оф. сайт:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134